# Rails: Making a third object save info from object 1 and 2 when I create a new object 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested

I have three models called Product, Category, and Categorization.

Product Model:

```
    attr_accessible :title, :description, :price, :image_url
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
```

Category Model:

```
    attr_accessible :name
    has_many :categorizations
    as_many :products, :through => :categorizations
```

Categorization Model:

```
    attr_accessible :category_id, :product_id
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :product
```

How can I create a categorization object when I create the product model? I have added the category select in the new product form.

Basically while it creates the new product object I want to push in the product_id and the selected category_id and create a new categorization object so I can associate the the product to the category.

_form.html for new product:

```
    <div>
        <%= f.label :title %>:<br />
        <%= f.text_field :title %><br />
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.label :description %>:<br />
        <%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 6 %>
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.label :price %>:<br />
        <%= f.text_field :price %><br />
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.label :image_url %>:<br />
        <%= f.text_field :image_url %><br />
      </div>

      <% @categories.each do |category| %>

      <div>
        <% f.fields_for :categorization do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'categorization_fields', :f => builder, :product => @product,         :category => category %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

products_controller :

```
    def index
        @products = Product.all
      end

      def new
        @category = Category.all
        @product = Product.new
        @categories = @category.find(params[:category])
        categorization = @product.categorizations.build
      end

      def create
        @product = Product.new(params[:product])
        if @product.save
          redirect_to products_path
        else
          render :new
        end
      end

      def edit
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
      end

      def update
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
        if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
          redirect_to @product
        else
          render :edit
        end
      end

      def show
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
      end

      def destroy
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
        @product.destroy
        redirect_to products_path
      end

    end
```

I can't get it to work like this with accepts_nested_attributes_for in the product model.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: am i approaching this the wrong way? I went through Ryan Bates railscast that basically said that doing the has_many :through is the best practice. So I am trying to figure out how to get this to work in that way. If not I can just do a simple join table to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add `autosave` option to your desired relations, e.g.:

```
has_many :categorizations, :autosave => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
```

This should save the `autosave`'d relation upon saving the model you declared the relation in.